# Проблема с циклом while+cin

Tags: c++, while, cin

Не выполняется вход последний `cin`, но при этом в первый `cin` вход выполняется и программа запрашивает данные. После окончания цикла, он естественно начинается по новой но в этот раз даже не выполняется вход в первый `cin`. На отладчике показывает будто последняя строка просто игнорируется.

```
     int stopCreatingStudents = 0;
     while (stopCreatingStudents != 1) {
         Student* student = new Student();
         std::string name;
         cout << "Input a name of a student: ";
         cin >> name;
         student->setName(name);
         newGroup.addStudent(student);
         cout << "Stop to create students?(0 - No, 1 - Yes): ";
         cin >> stopCreatingStudents;
     }
```

Comment: Покажите пример вводимых с клавиатуры данных

Comment: @avp Ivan Ivanov

Comment: Первый cin читает Ivan, второй пытается читать Ivanov, а должен читать **число**. Вот тут-то все и ломается. Используйте getline для чтения всей строки с именем. / Естественно, также, в правильной программе надо проверять результат каждого ввода данных на ошибки и конец файла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Входные данные:

> Ivan Ivanov

Код для считывания строки:

```
std::string name;
cin >> name;
```

В этом и проблема. [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) считывает только первое слово. Второе слово остаётся во входном потоке. Затем происходит попытка считать число:

```
int stopCreatingStudents = 0;
...
cin >> stopCreatingStudents;
```

Т.к. во входном потоке нет числа, то попытка считывания заканчивается ошибкой, и входной поток переходит в некорректное состояние. Все последующие попытки чтения игнорируются.

Чтобы считать всю строку, можно воспользоваться функцией [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Как-то так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> test;
    
    int stopCreatingStudents = 0;
    auto delim = decltype(cin)::traits_type::to_int_type('\n');
    while (!cin.fail() && stopCreatingStudents != 1) {
        std::string name;
        std::getline(cin, name);
        if (cin.fail())
            break;
        
        test.push_back(name);
        
        cin >> stopCreatingStudents;
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), delim);
    }
    
    for (const auto& str: test)
        cout << str << endl;
}
```

Ввод:

```
Ivan Ivanov
0
test test
    0      
foo foo
1
```

[Вывод](https://ideone.com/vSsUpu):

```
Ivan Ivanov
test test
foo foo
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: честно говоря, я не понимаю почему, но у меня getline не работает, но вы правы насчёт того что второе слово мешает потоку.

Comment: @ДмитрийГуща, что значит не работает?

Comment: смотрел на отладчике, и на шаге с заходом, отладчик не заходит в реализацию getline'a

Comment: @ДмитрийГуща, так сложно сказать в чём проблема. Попробуйте сформировать минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Не с вашим классом `Student`, а только `std::string` и `std::getline`. Чтобы любой смог запустить ваш пример и посмотреть в чём проблема. И задайте вопрос. То, что отладчик не заходит внутрь `std::getline` довольно _странно_.

Comment: честно вам скажу, мне даже трудно вам объяснить что нет так, я попытался реализовать эту ошибку в cpp.shell но там всё прекрасно сработало...

Comment: сейчас в std::getline заходит, но только со второго раза